# How to ravel numpy array in 's' path?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Given a 2D `np.array`:

```
arr = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
                [4, 5, 6],
                [7, 8, 9]])
```

How do I ravel it in an s-path such that I get

```
>>> sravel(arr)
array([1, 2, 3, 6, 5, 4, 7, 8, 9])
```

Additonally, I would like the option of going down the 0-axis first as well, i.e.

```
>>> sravel(arr, [0,1])
array([1, 4, 7, 8, 5, 2, 3, 6, 9])
```

here the second argument of the parenthesis indicates the order of axis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is any direct way to do that, but it's not hard to get that result:

```py
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
                [4, 5, 6],
                [7, 8, 9]])

arr2 = arr.copy()
arr2[1::2] = np.flip(arr[1::2], 1)
print(arr2.ravel())
# [1 2 3 6 5 4 7 8 9]

arr3 = arr.T.copy()
arr3[1::2] = np.flip(arr.T[1::2], 1)
print(arr3.ravel())
# [1 4 7 8 5 2 3 6 9]
```

---

EDIT: As pointed out by [scleronomic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7570817), the second case can also be done by means of an F-contiguous array:

```py
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
                [4, 5, 6],
                [7, 8, 9]])

# The array is copied with F order so ravel does not require another copy later
arr3 = arr.copy(order='F')
arr3[:, 1::2] = np.flip(arr3[:, 1::2], 0)
print(arr3.ravel(order='F'))
# [1 4 7 8 5 2 3 6 9]
```

Comment: you could also use `.ravel(order='F')` instead of transposing `arr3`

Comment: @Tian I have added how you could do it with F order.